# Table format support

Tags: support, markdown

Some systems, e.g. Trac, Wiki support the creation of tables.

Tables could be created in these systems by using `||`.

Is it possible to create tables on Stack Exchange as well? E.g:

|| City || Population ||
|| Utrecht || ~300K ||

Comment: See [Is there any markdown to create tables?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables) on Meta SE.

Comment: Cross-site dupe.  DAMN YOU, META SPLIT!

Comment: Note that the MSE request corresponding to this (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables) has a *status-declined*.  While I would personally love to see this implemented, sadly it doesn't look like it's going to happen.