# Posting Query Results

Tags: discussion

When a SQL query question is asked with sample data, I like to post the results of the query I wrote or edited.

**Example**

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
|   CPT     | Resource | Daily Cost |
+-----------+----------+------------+
|2017-06-11 |   RM1    |   1.53     |
|2017-06-11 |   RM2    |   1.79     |
|2017-06-11 |   RM3    |   2.00     |
|2017-06-12 |   RM1    |   1.00     | 
|2017-06-12 |   RM2    |   1.17     |
|2017-06-12 |   RM3    |   0.44     |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

I currently open Notepad and format the text there. Then I copy and paste it into my answer. Does anybody know of an easier way to get the results in the above format?

Comment: This one might help: https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/

Comment: @Rizier123, thanks. That is pretty useful.

Comment: If you're using MySQL, it already outputs results in that kind of table.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, No, Sql Server. When you chose `Results to Text`, it isn't formatted with the plus sign and dashes around the results.

Comment: Related: [Is there Markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566) (MSE) | [Table format support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270210) (MSO)